# How to understand a microcontroller's name?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I want to know how to get the information about a microcontroller from its name, like the  **STM32F407VG**. I know that the *F407VG* has got some information about the STM32 discovery board, but not sure what it is.

Comment: That information will be in the datasheet. Every manufacturer has their own numbering system.

Comment: There is no standard here. For example a PIC32MZ2048EFM is a 32-bit PIC, MZ series with 2048kb of flash memory and encryption engine. The part you described does not (without decoding) contain the flash memory size. This is all found in the respective device series data sheet. Some parts append additional data for package and packaging.

Comment: there are no doubt exceptions but this is one place where there is a common term.  datasheet,  the datasheet for a product generally will contain the ordering/part numbering information which then breaks down those numbers in some way, it may be the whole number just means blah, or that each digit means something or somewhere in between.  but as answered it is very specific to the product vendor and product family so you have to start with that vendor and look for a datasheet and or ordering information.

Comment: Datasheets, datasheets, datasheets. Whenever you have a question about a part or component, you start with the freakin datasheet. [Octopart](https://octopart.com/stm32f407vgt6-stmicroelectronics-20570110?r=sp) to the rescue.

Answer (score 28):

Each manufacturer labels its parts however it likes, usually explained on the datasheet or ordering information of its web site.  For this particular part, a **STM32F407VG** is in a 100-pin package (V) and has 1024 Kbytes of memory (G).

From the ordering page of the datasheet:

[image]
From STM32 datasheet https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f407vg.pdf